# How does the Mandrill API handle the send_at parameter for free accounts?

Tags: php, mandrill

Here’s the setup: we’re at a free level of Mandrill, using the API via PHP. Using the example scripts on the Mandrill site (link below) and changing just a few essentials (key, recipient, etc.)...

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html

...we’re finding that the “send_at” parameter is hanging us up. Here’s the response from the script if “send_at” is set to NULL or “”:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => someone@somewhere.com [status] => queued [_id] => 0c16bc002c874911ae36558881e5da77 ) )
```

If we assign a date/time to the “send_at” parameter (a date in the past as per [Mandrill API instructions](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html)), we get the following response from the script:

```
A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_PaymentRequired - Email scheduling is only available for accounts with a positive balance.
```

**What do we have to do with the “send_at” parameter to successfully use Mandrill API with a free account?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just omit the parameter altogether. It's optional and since you're not scheduling, you don't need to provide it. We'd recommend removing any of the optional parameters that you're not actually setting for testing purposes, and then add just the ones that you need or are specifying in your calls.

Comment: Roger that. Omitted the `send_at` parameter as well as the attachments. And a few others. Good to go. Thanks.